# Application what happens when no theme is specified

Tags: android, themes

I have been asked to make a new android application look the same as one of our older applications, the older product is based on version 8 of the SDK. In the manifest file there is no theme specified, however, for some reason a theme looks like it is being applied the backgrounds of all activities are black and the button control and the progress bars are yellow. I can't see anywhere in the application that a theme is specified, is there anywhere else to look other then the manifest file?

I have tried to create a new application targeting SDK 8 without specifying a theme but it seems to default to the standard android theme with white backgrounds and blue progress bars and highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme used in the SDK isn't necesserly the same theme that will appear on the devices.

When you don't specify a theme "which is your case", the default theme will be used. and almost every android device has its own default theme.

so if you are after a unified look you will have to create your own theme.

Comment: many thanks for your reply, it was the designer that was confusing me. Without a theme specified both applications look different in the designer but when you run them on the phone they look the same.